# Does the Udjat Eye blink when you enter the level with the Black Market in Spelunky 2?

Tags: spelunky-2

The [Udjat Eye](https://spelunky.fandom.com/wiki/Udjat_Eye/2) can be used to help track down the entrance to [The Black Market](https://spelunky.fandom.com/wiki/The_Black_Market/2) in all of the Spelunky games, including Spelunky 2. When you draw near the entrance of the black market, the eye will start blinking. That's pretty swell, but I've also come across articles and reddit posts indicating the the Udjat Eye also blinks once at the start of the level containing the black market.

For example, [this Polygon article](https://www.polygon.com/guides/2020/9/21/21431485/spelunky-2-find-black-market-location-gold-key-udjat-eye-store-shop) says:

> If the Udjat Eye icon opens and chirps once at the start of the level, as you can see in the image below, you know that level contains the Black Market.

I've yet to experience this start of level blinking, at least not that I've noticed. I've kept a close eye on it during my last few runs, and unless the blinking is really faint, I haven't seen it blinking when I enter a level containing the black market.

On my last few runs, however, The Black Market entrance spawned at the very bottom of the map. This leads me to suspect that the  Udjat Eye  doesn't automatically blink at the start of the Black Market level, and instead folks are just misinterpreting the regular proximity based blinking for a  "Start of level" blinking when the black market entrance just happens to be within range of the level entrance. Another possibility, though, is that this functionality was either intentionally changed or unintentionally broken during a  patch.

The wiki doesn't make any mention of this start of level blinking either, which heightens my suspension that other players are mistake about this behaviour.

**Does the Udjat Eye give any indication (blinking or otherwise) when you enter the level  with the Black Market in Spelunky 2?**